# How to fix ViewBinding build error on CodeLab

Tags: android-viewbinding, google-codelab

I recently went through the Codelab to update my Navigation and found a Nice way to handle SplitScreens and smaller as well as Wider screens on Android using BottomNavigation alternating with Drawer depend on Screen layout!

[Learn Jetpack Navigation Codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation) for the Codelab

[googlecodelabs /
android-navigation](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-navigation) for the GitHub Code

However:  Adopting this for ViewBinding present a problem that need fixing!

**By Adding**

```
buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        // for view binding:
        viewBinding true
    }
```

to the app:build.gradle and "Rebuild Project" yields an error

```
Configurations for navigation_activity.xml must agree on the root element's ID.
Missing ID:
 - layout-w960dp
 - layout-h470dp
@+id/drawer_layout:
 - layout
```

The Issue is that There is No ID's for the alternative layouts matching the main layout, however they are purposly different to accomplish the task.

**Can anyone Suggest a solve please**